# Type Mismatch Run Time error 13 for excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have requirement to write some function which will accept Range as input and I need to return value of first non empty cell. I have tried in one excel sheet and finding non empty cell was working fine. When I try with my project excel file it was not working. Basically for Find method of Range I am getting runtime error 13. Check below code and let me know what is the issue. I have noticed even in when I put Range.Row property it make "Row" as row in code ( in below code see Target.row).

```
 Sub Btn_GenerateChartClicked()
    If Range("E9") = "Scatter" Then
        MsgBox "Scatter is selected"
        Dim str As String
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("B12:I12")
        str = FindNonEmptyCellFromRange(rng)
       ' MsgBox str

    Else
        MsgBox "Bar is selected"
    End If
End Sub


Function FindNonEmptyCellFromRange(Target As Range) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Benchmarking_Project")
Dim foundRange As Range

Set foundRange = Target.Find("*", Cells(Target.row, 1), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
'Dim cellValue As String
'cellValue = foundRange.Value
FindNonEmptyCellFromRange = "Test"
'cellValue


End Function
```

Comment: So...I'm going to ask a dumb question, what are you doing with foundRange? In your code, you aren't doing anything with it. Do you plan to pass it to FindNonEmptyCellFromRange?

Comment: As I mentioned I pasted my RnD code here. Actually I return foundRange.Address from that function instead of hard coded "Test" value. I hope now it is clear. Actually I was getting error while setting foundRange as I mentioned in my question. So final goal was to resolve that. Sorry for confusion created due to some wrong code paste

Answer (score 1):

You can't `find` a target.

use `Cell.Find` and then once you have the cell selected use `Target.Address` to get the address of the cell

So your `CellValue` would become:

```
CellValue = FoundRange.Address
```

Although, your question is a little vague as your not doing anything practicle with this UDF anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not provide enough details and the function call does not return the non empty cell. Whatever happens your function will return only Test.

Anyway when going through the code, your range has a single row in it.

Issue seems to be with the following code

`Set foundRange = Target.Find("*", Cells(Target.row, 1), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)`

There is no need to specify the After Parameter `Cells(Target.row, 1)`

After parameters corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn’t searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.

Try to change that code to

```
Set foundRange = Target.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
```

The following code may work for you

```
Sub Btn_GenerateChartClicked()
    If Range("E9") = "Scatter" Then
        MsgBox "Scatter is selected"
        Dim str As String
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("B12:I12")
        str = GetFirstNonEmptyCell(rng)
       ' MsgBox str

    Else
        MsgBox "Bar is selected"
    End If
End Sub


Public Function GetFirstNonEmptyCell(Target As Range)
    Dim startCell As Range, firstNonEmptyCell As Range

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) <> "" Then
            Found_Address = c.Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetFirstNonEmptyCell = Found_Address

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ian your suggestion about not to use Cells(Target.Row,1) in Find method is right. I got my mistake. In that I have put column index as 1 but it should be 2 because my selected range is from Column B which means column index 2. So I got actually error because there is no column index 1 in that range. So if I put 2 instead of 1 in above mentioned call then it is working fine. Yes your right that I was not returning actually value of last non empty cell as that was my R&D code I kept changing it. So while posting it I forgot to change it. Thank you all for your reply